# C++ How to initialize static variable of an class which contains a mutex

Tags: c++, static, initialization, mutex

I have a templated class with a mutex:

```
template <typename T> class A {
 public:
  std::mutex classMutex;
  T value;
  A(T initValue) : value(initValue){}
};
```

and a second class with a static member of the first class:

```
class B{
  static A<double> test;
}; 
A<double> B::test = 0.0;
```

I keep getting an error:
"copying variable of type 'A' invokes deleted constructor"

Comment: `A<double> B::test{0.0};`

Comment: @rafix07 working thanks, could you explain, why this makes a difference?

Comment: `mutex` is neither copyable nor movable, it means all copy and move operations are deleted by default (for class which contains mutex as data variable) -  `A(const A&) = delete`, `A(A&&) = delete` etc.  When you call `A<double> B::test = 0.0` double value `0.0` is converted to `A<double>(0.0)` so you have `A<double> B::test = A<double>(0.0)` because copy construction is deleted compiler refuse this line. With `{}` you are just calling `A<double>(0.0)` constructor without any copy syntax.

Comment: @rafix07 +1; you should create an answer, I think, so that it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @rafix07:

The solution is:

```
A<double> B::test{0.0};
```

"mutex is neither copyable nor movable, it means all copy and move operations are deleted by default (for class which contains mutex as data variable)

```
 A(const A&) = delete,
 A(A&&) = delete
```

etc. When you call

```
A<double> B::test = 0.0
```

double value 0.0 is converted to

```
A<double>(0.0)
```

so you have

```
A<double> B::test = A<double>(0.0)
```

because copy construction is deleted compiler refuse this line. With {} you are just calling A(0.0) constructor without any copy syntax." by @rafix07